# How to query Azure SQL database using Python async?

Tags: python, asynchronous, azure-sql-database, python-asyncio, pyodbc

I'm stuck and can't figure out a workable way to connect asynchronously to an Azure SQL database using Python.

I've tried `asyncio`, `pyodbc` and `asyncpg` to no avail.

I *think* this is close...

```py
import asyncio
import pyodbc

async def query_azure_sql_db():
  connection_string = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:<mySERVER>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=sqldbstockdata;Uid=<myUN>;Pwd=<myPW>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;'

  async with pyodbc.connect(connection_string) as conn:
    async with conn.cursor() as cursor:
      query = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.<myTABLE>'
      await cursor.execute(query)
      results = cursor.fetchall()
      return results

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
results = loop.run_until_complete(query_azure_sql_db())
print(results)
```

But results in this cryptic error: `AttributeError: __aenter__`

I'm open to other libraries.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `pyodbc.connect` is a function and does not implement async context manager, so why you are getting the `AttributeError`. I recommend using [`aioodbc`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aioodbc) instead of `pyodbc` as it provides the same functionality as `async` methods. You can also make it work with `async with` by implementing the `__aenter__` and `__aexit__` dunder methods.

```py
import asyncio
import aioodbc

class AsyncPyodbc:
    def __init__(self, dsn, autocommit=False, ansi=False, timeout=0,
                 loop=None, executor=None, echo=False, after_created=None, **kwargs):
        self._connection: aioodbc.Connection = aioodbc.connect(dsn=dsn, autocommit=autocommit, ansi=ansi,
                                                               loop=loop, executor=executor, echo=echo,
                                                               timeout=timeout, after_created=after_created, **kwargs)

    async def __aenter__(self) -> aioodbc.Connection:
        return await self._connection

    async def __aexit__(self, *_):
        return await self._connection.close()
```

This will require an event loop and will be used as follows.

```py
async def query_azure_sql_db():
    connection_string = (
        'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
        'Server=tcp:<mySERVER>.database.windows.net,1433;'
        'Database=sqldbstockdata;Uid=<myUN>;Pwd=<myPW>;'
        'Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;'
    )
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    async with AsyncPyodbc(connection_string, loop=loop) as conn:
        ...
```